# Can I automate this with Python? Sending emails with a file that needs to be updated

Tags: python, excel

I've been learning Python for over a month now, so I am still very new to it. I'm planning to use it to automate several boring tasks at work. I'd like to verify with you whether one of these tasks can be automated at all.

So, basically every day I need to:

Open an Excel spreadsheet with certain data that is pulled from another data base. The data is updated automatically whenever the Excel spreadsheet is being opened.

Copy a table from this Excel spreadsheet

Paste it into an Outlook email

Send the email to certain email addresses.

Can I automate this process so that it happens independently every day at a certain time?

My only concern is:

i) The data in the Excel spreadsheet is updated only when it is opened. Can a program do this on its own?

I'll greatly appreciate your advice!

Comment: what do you mean by copy a table from excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Not my area of expertise but you can run a task scheduler to start at a specific time with a vb script (.vbs file). it will start excel and open and run/call a marco:
notepad save file as .vbs the following:

'Input Excel File's Full Path
ExcelFilePath = "C:\filename.xlsm"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File (eg. module1 running a sub called macrosubname)
MacroPath = "module1.macrosubname"

'Create an instance of Excel
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
ExcelApp.Visible = True  'or "False"

'Open Excel File
Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
ExcelApp.Run MacroPath